# OutOfMemoryError due to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage

Tags: selenium, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I have recently started looking into htmlunit. I am troubleshooting an out of memory issue caused in my application, eclise MAT is showing there is a huge Retained Heap of two objects if HtmlPage object, can anyone help he identity the route cause.

**UPDATE:** I have create heap dump file using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` command as argument for JVM.

[image]

Comment: Code trials please

Comment: @DebanjanB I am analyzing heap dump file of entire application.

Comment: How to provide code trails ?

Comment: How are you trying to get the `heap dump file of entire application`?

Comment: Using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` command as argument for JVM

Comment: Update the question with this information for a proper analysis

Comment: @DebanjanB question updated...